# Regexp to parse test output and print only failure cases

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am trying to parse the output log of unit tests using a regular expression.
My goal is to print only the details of the error cases.

Here is an example of the output:

```
[ RUN      ] testname 1
Success log
[       OK ] testname 1
[ RUN      ] testname 2
Failure details 1
Failure details 1
[  FAILED  ] testname 2
[ RUN      ] testname 3
Success log
[       OK ] testname 3
[ RUN      ] testname 4
Failure details 2
Failure details 2
[  FAILED  ] testname 4
[ RUN      ] testname
Success log
[       OK ] testname
```

The output should be:

```
[ RUN      ] testname 2
Failure details 1
Failure details 1
[  FAILED  ] testname 2
[ RUN      ] testname 4
Failure details 2
Failure details 2
[  FAILED  ] testname 4
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```sh
grep -Pzo "(?s)^\[ RUN      \].*?^\[  FAILED  \].*?$" test.log
```

However, the output is not correct because the sequence `.*?` does not exclude the `[       OK ]`.

In practice, I get two matches:

1.

```
[ RUN      ] testname 1
Success log
[       OK ] testname 1
[ RUN      ] testname 2
Failure details 1
Failure details 1
[  FAILED  ] testname 2
```

2.

```
[ RUN      ] testname 3
Success log
[       OK ] testname 3
[ RUN      ] testname 4
Failure details 2
Failure details 2
[  FAILED  ] testname 4
```

I think I should use something called Negative Lookahead, but I wasn't able to get it working.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

```sh
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="[ RUN "} chomp; print $/,$_ if /FAILED/' ip.txt
[ RUN      ] testname 2
Failure details 1
Failure details 1
[  FAILED  ] testname 2
[ RUN      ] testname 4
Failure details 2
Failure details 2
[  FAILED  ] testname 4
```

- `BEGIN{$/="[ RUN "}` change input record separator from newline to `[ RUN`
- `chomp` remove record separator from each record
- `print $/,$_ if /FAILED/` print record separator and the record if it contains `FAILED`

This is similar to

```sh
gawk -v RS='\\[ RUN ' -v ORS= '/FAILED/{print "[ RUN " $0}' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
\[.*RUN.*\]+.+\nFailure.*\nFailure.*\n\[.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/i0aacp/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

[`(.*\d\n(?:F.*\n)+.*\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/s85o9F/1)

This captures lines ending with a digit (`\d\n`) followed by one or more instances of `F.*\n`.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl

```
perl -0777 -ne'print grep /Failure/, split /^(?=\[ RUN)/m' test.log
```

This prints the desired output with the provided example in `test.log`

The [`-0777`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) enables "slurp" mode so the whole file is read into [`$_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables). This is [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on `^`, matching line beginning with [`/m`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), with a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) for the pattern `[ RUN`. The list returned by `split` is passed through [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), which passes blocks with `Failure`, and this output list is printed.